# How can I view image through URL from remote Ubuntu server? Python

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-16.04

I have a picture on my remote ubuntu(16.04) server, so I want to paste it to my Github Readme.md file.

So how can I view (not download, not copy) that image through URL, for instance, server_ip_address/img.png

Thanks for any help or idea!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to host resources on your ubuntu server you should install a webserver (apache / nginx) if ones not installed already. Heres docs for ubuntu apache: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-ubuntu-16-04.

Move the image to the webserver's document root (likely /var/www/html) so that you can access it via a url. If you have a static ip on the host then you should be able to access it via http://static_ip/img.png and add that url to Readme.md

Comment: Okay, I made it, buut it doesn't work at all(( I've installed nginx to my server, then moved my img to /var/www/html !!  

Could you please make some template, how I have to configure my nginx webserver?

Comment: Try following @d g posted link to setup an apache server. This should work.